# How to avoid race condition for separate input and output queues?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function `process` which transforms items. Under the hood, it puts an item into an input queue, and takes result from an output queue. The transformation itself happens in a separate thread. A simplified example:

```
def process(item):
    inp_queue.put(item)    # (1)
    return out_queue.get() # (2)

def separate_thread():
    while True:
        item = inp_queue.get()
        processed_item = do_work(item)
        out_queue.put(processed_item)
```

I call the function `process` from a number of *other* threads. I am afraid that there could be a race condition, if two threads call lines (1) and (2) in this order:

```
thread1: (1)
thread2: (2)
thread2: (2) # thread2 gets thread1's result!
thread1: (1)
```

Is this race condition possible, and if yes, how could I avoid it?

Comment: If some items are specifically intended for thread 1 and some for thread 2, why not use separate queues for the threads?

Comment: What is the reason that the processing happens in a separate thread if "process" (and its thread) is blocked anyway until the result is available?

Comment: @Grismar I have an unknown number of calling threads, e.g. HTTP connections

Comment: @MichaelButscher The reason is in order to do the processing, I must call a separate binary over which I have no control. So in truth it is not a separate thread, but a separate process called via `subprocess.Popen`. `inp_queue` and `out_queue` are filled with its stdin and stdout.

Comment: You can guard the whole communication with the subprocess with a global "Lock" or "RLock" object to avoid the race condition (which is really possible).

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thank you! It looks like an obvious solution in retrospect :) However, I am new to multithreading.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Won't it be better if he put lock when the size of the queue is `<=1`. Because if process take some time to return output then queue will be blocked for no reason because other thread can write it without creating and race conditoin.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi Writing to queue means here actually writing to stdin of the subprocess (because writing to a Python queue would need nearly no time and isn't worth the hassle). If the amount of data to write is small it isn't worth the hassle to juggle with multiple locks, too. If the amount is large there may be a buffer overflow which will also lock the thread, therefore no gain.

Comment: There's no point in using multiple threads if you're going to make everything serial with a global lock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a race condition.  Since you don't necessarily want to process the outputs in the order that they are generated, you should just not use a queue for the outputs.

Typically, you implement this pattern like so:

1. You still use an input queue, but each item you put into that queue is a "request" object that includes, not only the input parameters, but also a place to put the output, and something to wait on until it is complete.  In python, an Event or Semaphore (with initial value 0) are good choices for the thing to wait on.
2. The `process()` function creates a request, pushes it into the queue, and then waits on its completion object.
3. A worker thread will eventually pull out the request, do the work, fill in the result field, and trigger the completion object. (`event.set()` or `semaphore.release()`)
4. The `process()` function wakes up and collects the output from the request object.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please provide some examples of how can I implement "a place to put the output"? I don't know any good ways to send data between threads except queues.

Comment: It's just an empty field in the request object, that the worker can fill in

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is race condition happening. thread1 and thread2 are trying to access the function process simultaneously.

Please go through these links for better understanding:

[Sharing a queue among multiple threads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sharing-queue-among-three-threads/)

[Multithreading in Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-python-set-2-synchronization/)